# Есть калькулятор. Как одной кнопкой менять открывающие скобочки на закрывающие?

Tags: javascript, html, css, калькулятор

При нажатии на кнопку "()" появляется открывающаяся скобка "(", как заменить открывающуюся скобку на закрывающуюся ")" при повторном нажатии на туже самую кнопку "()"?

```js
var textid = document.getElementById('textid')
let expreshion = '';

function input(num) { // отображает в строке ввода нажимаемые цифры
  expreshion += num;
  textid.value = expreshion;
}

function ac() { // обнуляет строку ввода
  expreshion = '';
  textid.value = expreshion;
}

function equal() { // выводит результат выражения
  if (textid.value !== '') {
    textid.value = eval(textid.value);
  }
}

function beckspace() { // удаляет последний символ
  let value = document.getElementById("textid").value;
  textid.value = value.substr(0, value.length - 1);
  expreshion = textid.value
}
```

```css
.kalkulator {
  width: 300px;
  height: 480px;
  background: rgb(10, 10, 10);
  color: aliceblue;
  border-radius: 4%;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #afafaf;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#textid {
  text-align: right;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(177, 177, 184);
  width: 91%;
  border-radius: 5%;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.battons {
  margin: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "AS skobki persent division" "seven aigh nine myltiply" "four five six minus" "one two fhree plus" "zero dot beckspace equal";
  grid-gap: 7px;
  justify-items: center;
}

.batton {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 58px;
  user-select: none;
}

.batton:hover {
  filter: brightness(120%);
}

.batton:active {
  filter: brightness(80%);
}

.batton.rg {
  background: rgb(130, 68, 212);
}

.batton.bl {
  background: rgba(93, 169, 240, 0.774);
}

.batton.bj {
  background: rgba(32, 182, 241, 0.589);
}

.img.beckspace {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Калькулятор</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="kalkulator" >

        <input id = 'textid'  placeholder="0">
        <div class="battons">
            <div onclick="ac()" class="batton rg ac">AC</div>
            <div onclick="input('(')" class="batton skobki bl ">()</div>
            <div onclick="input('%')" class="batton persent bl ">%</div>
            <div onclick="input('/')" class="batton division bl ">/</div>
    
            <div onclick="input(7)" class="batton seven">7</div>
            <div onclick="input(8)" class="batton eight">8</div>
            <div onclick="input(9)" class="batton nine">9</div>
            <div onclick="input('*')" class="batton myltiply bl">*</div>
    
            <div onclick="input(4)" class="batton four">4</div>
            <div onclick="input(5)" class="batton five">5</div>
            <div onclick="input(6)" class="batton six">6</div>
            <div onclick="input('-')" class="batton minus bl">-</div>
    
            <div onclick="input(1)" class="batton one">1</div>
            <div onclick="input(2)" class="batton two">2</div>
            <div onclick="input(3)" class="batton fhree">3</div>
            <div onclick="input('+')" class="batton plus bl">+</div>
    
            <div onclick="input(0)" class="batton zero">0</div>
            <div onclick="input('.')" class="batton dot">.</div>
            <div onclick="beckspace()" class="batton beckspace"  >X</div>
            <div onclick="equal()" class="batton equal bj">=</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Надо не скобочки проверять, а предыдущий токен. Если там умножить/сложить или открывающая скобка тогда там может быть открывающая. Если там число тогда закрывающая. Ну и так далее

Comment: Я думаю, мы о разном.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код работает. Не знаю на сколько он качественный. Метод `brace();`

```js
var textid = document.getElementById('textid')
let expreshion = '';

function input(num) { // отображает в строке ввода нажимаемые цифры
  expreshion += num;
  textid.value = expreshion;
}

function brace() {
  const braces = textid.value.split("");
  const left_brace = braces.filter(el => el=== "(").length;
  const right_brace = braces.filter(el => el === ")").length;

  if (left_brace > right_brace) {
    input(")");
  } else {
    input("(");
  }
}

function ac() { // обнуляет строку ввода
  expreshion = '';
  textid.value = expreshion;
}

function equal() { // выводит результат выражения
  if (textid.value !== '') {
    textid.value = eval(textid.value);
  }
}

function beckspace() { // удаляет последний символ
  let value = document.getElementById("textid").value;
  textid.value = value.substr(0, value.length - 1);
  expreshion = textid.value
}
```

```css
.kalkulator {
  width: 300px;
  height: 480px;
  background: rgb(10, 10, 10);
  color: aliceblue;
  border-radius: 4%;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #afafaf;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#textid {
  text-align: right;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(177, 177, 184);
  width: 91%;
  border-radius: 5%;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.battons {
  margin: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "AS skobki persent division" "seven aigh nine myltiply" "four five six minus" "one two fhree plus" "zero dot beckspace equal";
  grid-gap: 7px;
  justify-items: center;
}

.batton {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 58px;
  user-select: none;
}

.batton:hover {
  filter: brightness(120%);
}

.batton:active {
  filter: brightness(80%);
}

.batton.rg {
  background: rgb(130, 68, 212);
}

.batton.bl {
  background: rgba(93, 169, 240, 0.774);
}

.batton.bj {
  background: rgba(32, 182, 241, 0.589);
}

.img.beckspace {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Калькулятор</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="kalkulator" >

        <input id = 'textid'  placeholder="0">
        <div class="battons">
            <div onclick="ac()" class="batton rg ac">AC</div>
            <div onclick="brace()" class="batton skobki bl ">()</div>
            <div onclick="input('%')" class="batton persent bl ">%</div>
            <div onclick="input('/')" class="batton division bl ">/</div>
    
            <div onclick="input(7)" class="batton seven">7</div>
            <div onclick="input(8)" class="batton eight">8</div>
            <div onclick="input(9)" class="batton nine">9</div>
            <div onclick="input('*')" class="batton myltiply bl">*</div>
    
            <div onclick="input(4)" class="batton four">4</div>
            <div onclick="input(5)" class="batton five">5</div>
            <div onclick="input(6)" class="batton six">6</div>
            <div onclick="input('-')" class="batton minus bl">-</div>
    
            <div onclick="input(1)" class="batton one">1</div>
            <div onclick="input(2)" class="batton two">2</div>
            <div onclick="input(3)" class="batton fhree">3</div>
            <div onclick="input('+')" class="batton plus bl">+</div>
    
            <div onclick="input(0)" class="batton zero">0</div>
            <div onclick="input('.')" class="batton dot">.</div>
            <div onclick="beckspace()" class="batton beckspace"  >X</div>
            <div onclick="equal()" class="batton equal bj">=</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: мне нрав) + клацнул

Comment: А в чём смысл каждый раз парсить строку и считать кол-во скобок? Чем это будет отличать от того что я просто буду вставлять `(` или `)` по очереди не проверяя кол-во?

Comment: перечитал вопрос, перечитал ответ, попробовал калькулятор (он красивый, не скроешь), но похоже не решает задачу автора.

Answer (score 1):

Автор где-то ставил вопрос о валидации? Проверке выражений? Отрабатывании ситуаций, когда введенная скобка удаляется вручную?

Задача сформулирована максимально примитивная и решать ее надо так же. Тупо, например, задать переменную `isClosingBracket = false` и на нажатие кнопки выдавать что-то вроде: `if (isClosingBracket) write "(" else write ")"; isClosingBracket = !isClosingBracket;`.

П.С. автор:

- "button"
- "backspace"
- "percent"
- "brackets"
- "calculator"
- "multiply"
- "three"
- "expression"

учите английский, от ваших переменных и классов кровавые слезы на глазах...

Comment: Спасибо за критику, я только начал изучать JS, подскажите пожалуйста как бы вы переименовали классы и переменные?

Comment: В полном соответствии с грамматикой английского языка (JS тут не при чем). Я же вам написал в ответе, в постскриптуме.